# How to recover .cs files after a republish of my webservices to the same location?

Tags: wcf, publish, file-recovery

I tried to republish my WCF solution in Visual Studio and unchecked the checkbox "Leave extra files on destination (do not delete)". Now my whole solution has gone bad. Visual Studio can't find any of my files. Does anybody know a solution to this stupidity of mine? Any help would be MUCH appreciated!!

I found the solution. The files were also stored at '/Libraries/Documents/IIShosted'.

Comment: If you solved your problem you should post the solution as an answer; you'll get a shiny new SO badge and your answer may help someone searching for the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [#7 on MSDN under Creating a Publish Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx).

> **The publish process deletes files on the destination server under the following circumstances:**
>
> 1. You clear the Leave extra files on destination option.
> 2. The files already exist on the destination server in the publish location or in any subfolders.
> 3. The same files do not exist in the same folders in the Web application project.